# Rails Testing: Why should one use Rspec2 over Stock testing environment rails provide by default

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I am very new to rails3 and ruby as such. I am looking to setup testing for my rails app. The one which is provided by rails ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html ) is different from what I find while searching over web for rails testing. People mostly prefer Rspec2 over the stock testing environment.

Is it true? I might be wrong but I want to choose a proper testing environment for my new webapp. Can anyone tell me the difference between the stock testing environment and Rspec2. Why would someone consider either of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no proper way to answer this question. Why is red better than blue? People have preferences and at one point Rspec2 became something of a de facto standard. I think after that a lot of people just started using it because everyone else already used it. DDH — the creator of Ruby on Rails — really dislikes Rspec and [clearly favors Test::Unit](http://www.rubyinside.com/dhh-offended-by-rspec-debate-4610.html). Personally I use Rspec at work because the majority of the team likes it and use Ruby 1.9's [Minitest](http://www.bootspring.com/2010/09/22/minitest-rubys-test-framework/) for my private projects.

My suggestion for you: look at the different testing frameworks, see which one you feel comfortable with and use that. The important thing is that you test, not what you test with.